# Does this sort order have a name?

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting

Does the following sort order have a name? Given an index, sort the list in order of proximity to that index.

```
Collections.sort(items, new Comparator<String>() {

         @Override
         public int compare(String o1, String o2) {

             int distanceA = (int)Math.abs(centerIndex - items.indexOf(o1));
             int distanceB = (int)Math.abs(centerIndex - items.indexOf(o2));

             int result = distanceA - distanceB;
             return result;
         }
}
```

So for the list `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]` and a centerIndex of 7, the sorted list would be: `[7,8,6,9,5,10,4,3,2,1]`

Comment: Why does the sorted list begin with `7,8,6` and `7,6,8` is not acceptable? It seems to me 6 and 8 both have the same distance to 7.

Comment: @Tunkai. The sort may or may not be stable. This one does not appear to be since the comparator does not check for the absolute sign if the distances are equal.

Comment: @Tunaki Where does it say that `7,6,8` is not acceptable?

Comment: @Fidel If it turns out that you "discovered" this sort order, you get naming rights. Only YOU can answer the question in that case.

Comment: @CedricReichenbach It is implied by the sentence "the sorted list would be...". It could be that, but it could also be something else.

Comment: I hereby declare this a pivot sort.

Comment: BTW, this particular snippet, with your inputs, just reverses the list: [link](https://ideone.com/5t8OMX)

Answer (score 1):

"Sort by distance" is an entirely appropriate name since your `compare` method is a metric or distance function. [See wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_(mathematics))